# Tensorflow List Devices only shows XLA_GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

When running `device_lib.list_local_devices()` in tensorflow, I get the following output:

```
2019-02-22 21:48:37.810736: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:300] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error
2019-02-22 21:48:37.810812: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:163] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: nmddesktop
2019-02-22 21:48:37.810830: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:170] hostname: nmddesktop
2019-02-22 21:48:37.810888: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:194] libcuda reported version is: 390.77.0
2019-02-22 21:48:37.810932: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:198] kernel reported version is: 390.77.0
2019-02-22 21:48:37.810945: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:305] kernel version seems to match DSO: 390.77.0
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 12210423598302768364
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 16374639101419597531
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 2828848118151845005
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
]
```

What I find strange is that it lists `XLA_GPU` but not GPU (like it does with CPU).

Does anyone have any ideas? This is on Ubuntu 18.04, I have a GTX 970 GPU, Tensorflow version 1.12.0.

Comment: you should verify the CUDA install

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: If you are using CUDA 9.0 above, check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253395/tensorflow-only-sees-xla-gpus-and-cannot-use-them/57767720#57767720