# Tensorflow only sees XLA_GPUs and cannot use them

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have a machine with 8 GPUS (4x GPU GTX 1080 Ti of 11 Gb de RAM and 4x RTX 1080) and cannot get tensorflow to use them correctly (or at all).

When I do

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

It prints

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 5295519098812813462
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 12186007115805339517
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:1"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 17706271046686153881
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:2"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 14710290295129432533
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:3"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 1381213064943868400
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:4"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 12093982778662340719
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:5"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 682960671898108683
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:6"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 9901240111105546679
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:7"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 8442134369143872649
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 1687638086072792879
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
].
```

If I try to use the GPUs for anything, nvidia-smi says they are occupied, but running at 0%, and the speed of the task shows tensorflow is just using the CPU.
In other machines, with the same setup, it prints too `'/device:GPU:2'` along with `'/device:XLA_GPU:2'` (for instance), and tensorflow is able to use them with no problem.

I have already seen similar problems and solutions but none seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's most likely that you have incompatible CUDA installed. If you install tensorflow with pip, then check https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu to see tensorflow version and corresponding CUDA version (cudnn version too). Make sure you have `correct` version of tensorflow, CUDA and cudnn installed. Or, you could choose to build tensorflow from source, but I have less experience on it, you may Google it by yourself:) Good luck!